# xslt invoke template only when parameter is provided

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have xlst in which I want to invoke template only when it's value is provided from java (set with `transformer.setParameter(paramName, paramValue)`). I'm using saxon 9 HE.

This is my stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="supplierLogo" as="xs:string" required="no" select="''"/>

    <!-- add logo -->
    <xsl:template match="/INVOICES/INVOICE/SUPPLIER_LOGO">
        <xsl:if test="not($supplierLogo = '')">
            <SUPPLIER_LOGO>
                <xsl:value-of select="$supplierLogo"/>
            </SUPPLIER_LOGO>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1. How to run template conditionally?
2. Now when value is not provided element SUPPLIER_LOGO is removed from my xml. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then use

```
<xsl:template match="/INVOICES/INVOICE/SUPPLIER_LOGO[$supplierLogo = ''"/>

<xsl:template match="/INVOICES/INVOICE/SUPPLIER_LOGO[$supplierLogo != '']">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$supplierLogo"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```